# Changing c++ opencv code to android code

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

Hi I want to change perspective of image and merge it with antoher image. I found example wrote with opencv library in c++, and i tried to convert this to android, but i have error no implementation found for long org.opencv.highgui.
This is my code:

```
public class TransformationImage {
private MatOfPoint2f pointsOfSuperimposedImage;
private MatOfPoint2f pointsOfMainImage;
private Mat imageMain;
private Mat imagelogo;

public TransformationImage(String imageMainPath, String imageLogoPath) {
    this.imagelogo = Highgui.imread(imageLogoPath);
    this.imageMain = Highgui.imread(imageMainPath);
    pointsOfMainImage = new MatOfPoint2f();
    pointsOfSuperimposedImage = new MatOfPoint2f();
}

public Bitmap transformTwoImages(){
    Mat finalTransformedImage;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(552, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    setMainImageVectors();
    setAppliedImagePosition();
    setWarpPerspectiveOfTwoImages();
    finalTransformedImage = showFinal(pointsOfMainImage, pointsOfMainImage);
    Utils.matToBitmap(finalTransformedImage, bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}

private Mat showFinal(Mat firstImage, Mat secondImage){
    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Mat gray_inv = new Mat();
    Mat src1final = new Mat();
    Mat src2final = new Mat();
    cvtColor(secondImage, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(gray, gray, 0, 255, 0);
    bitwise_not(gray, gray_inv);
    firstImage.copyTo(src2final, gray_inv);
    secondImage.copyTo(src1final, gray);
    addWeighted(src1final, 0, src2final, 0, 0, src1final);
    return src1final;
}
private void setWarpPerspectiveOfTwoImages(){
    Imgproc.warpPerspective(imagelogo, imageMain, Calib3d.findHomography(pointsOfSuperimposedImage, pointsOfMainImage), imageMain.size());
}
private void setMainImageVectors(){
    List<Point> src_pnt = new ArrayList<>();
    Point p0 = new Point(0, 0);
    src_pnt.add(p0);
    Point p1 = new Point(552, 0);
    src_pnt.add(p1);
    Point p2 = new Point(0, 256);
    src_pnt.add(p2);
    Point p3 = new Point(552, 256);
    src_pnt.add(p3);
    pointsOfMainImage.push_back(Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(src_pnt));
}
private void setAppliedImagePosition(){
    List<Point> src_pnt = new ArrayList<>();
    Point p0 = new Point(0, 0);
    src_pnt.add(p0);
    Point p1 = new Point(50, 0);
    src_pnt.add(p1);
    Point p2 = new Point(50, 20);
    src_pnt.add(p2);
    Point p3 = new Point(20, 0);
    src_pnt.add(p3);
    pointsOfSuperimposedImage.push_back(Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(src_pnt));
}
}
```

And here is a sample of code in c++ http://ramsrigoutham.com/2014/06/14/perspective-projection-with-homography-opencv/#comment-8114

I import opencv library into my project in android studio by import module.

Comment: Did you start the service connection to the openCV Manager? See tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#dev-with-ocv-on-android

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not follow proper way. You can not directly conver c++ code to java.
To used openCV library in java code they provide java wrapper class for android development. and you must download and import following library -javacpp.jar
-javacv.jar
-javacv-android-arm.jar

For more detail step please see [this](http://javacv4android.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-import-javacv-libraries-to.html) blog

This one may help you. If you want more help then feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer following link ,this may be help you.

[link1](http://nex-g.blogspot.in/2013/04/step-by-step-tutorial-to-android-ndk-in.html)
[link2](http://android-code-zen.blogspot.in/2013/05/hello-world-android-ndk-eclipse.html)